# asp.net 404 The resource cannot be found

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a asp.net web forms c# application. All these days no issues, but now getting a weird error.

I have a page genm.aspx file. If there is a error on the page, I am getting **COMPILATION ERROR**
which is fine, but if every thing is OK on the page and open the page getting

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.

**Note:**
1. The other aspx files are working properly with no issues.
2. Under properties I set the target framework as **4.5**, but in the error message it shows as Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18044

Please help.

Comment: The version you get in the error is correct. With .NET 4.5, Microsoft didn't change the version numbers because they wanted .NET 4.5 to be an in place replacement. See e.g. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NETVersioningAndMultiTargetingNET45IsAnInplaceUpgradeToNET40.aspx for more information.

Comment: What's fine about a compilation error? Please solve that and see what happens.

Comment: Pieter: Thanks for the info on asp.net version

Comment: Alexander: There are no errors on the page. But to proof the page is there, I added some run time errors and that time I am getting compilation error. And when I remove the added error, get resource not found 404 message. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I looked more into the issue and found that in the code behind I have a file IO which is opening up a numeric.txt file, which is missing.

Wish the error code gives 404 to the IO file, instead of showing it as .aspx resource not found.

thank you.

Comment: Did you miss the part in parenthesizes that says, ' (or one of its dependencies)'

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Event viewer to get the error cause? try it out : http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/40108/how-to-use-event-viewer/
then Post the error completely please.

Comment: I checked in the event viewer, but there is nothing logged for "404 The resource cannot be found" issue. Any other way to see the messages? Thanks.